# How to use null value IN operator SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, null, isnull

I have a problem with column [Transfer-from Code].
There is like 30 different values.
But I need all values for [Transfer-from Code] which are x1, x2 and NULL.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
       ILE.[Item No_]           AS ItemNo
      ,It.[Tariff No_]          AS TariffNo
      ,ILE.[Posting Date]       AS PostingDate
      ,ILE.[Location Code]      AS LocationCode
      ,ILE.[Quantity]           AS Qty
      ,CASE 
       WHEN ILE.[Entry Type] = 0 THEN 'Purchase'    
       WHEN ILE.[Entry Type] = 4 THEN 'Transfer'
       ELSE '' END AS EntryType
      ,Trp.[Transfer-from Code] AS SourceLocation
      -- Try to cast from below all NULL values to be test, so I can use them into IN operator. Still not working
      --,ISNULL(Trp.[Transfer-from Code], 'test') AS SourceLocation

FROM [MDR].[dbo].[nav_XX$Item_Ledger_Entry]             AS ILE 
LEFT JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_XX$Item]                     AS It ON ILE.[Item No_] = It.No_
LEFT JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_XX$Transfer_Receipt_Header]  AS Trp on ILE.[Document No_] = Trp.No_

WHERE ILE.[Entry Type] IN ('0','4')
AND ILE.[Posting Date] > '2019-12-11 00:00:00.000'
AND ILE.[Location Code] IN ('X24','XB16')

--From this part below, everything don't work. I'm getting only the values for X1 and X2.

--AND TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1','X2',NULL)

--AND TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1','X2','test')

/*
AND TRP.[Transfer-from Code] = 'X1'
OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code] = 'X2'
--OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code]= NULL
OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code]= 'test'
*/
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: `field IN (...) OR field IS NULL`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko
AND TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1','X2', IS NULL)  it not working. I receive error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Comment: `where TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1','X2') is not false` will return x1, x2 and null.

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
AND (TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1','X2') OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IS NULL)
```

Check for `NULL`s only with the operators `IS` and `IS NOT`.
Never with `=` or `IN` because the result of a comparison to `NULL` is always `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`Null` has a *special meaning* it stands for *unknown*, *doesn't matter* etc. That's why it has *special syntax* to check:

```
 field IS NULL
```

In your case

```
 (field IN (item1, item2, item3) OR field IS NULL)
```

E.g.

```
 (TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IN ('X1', 'X2') OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IS NULL)
```

please, note that even if text like

```
 field = NULL
```

or

```
 field IN (null)
```

is *syntactically correct*, the outcome will be neither `true` nor `false` but `NULL` when `field` is `NULL` (Yes, `NULL = NULL` is *not* `true`):

> if `field` with *unknown value* (`Null`) equals to some other *unknown value* (`Null`)?
>   It's *unknown* (`Null`)

Comment: Note that `field = NULL` and `field IN (null)` are _not_ valid ANSI SQL syntax. (But accepted by many dbms products.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"="` with `"IS"`, add `"()"` and it will work.

Try :

```
AND 
(
    TRP.[Transfer-from Code] = 'X1'
    OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code] = 'X2'
    OR TRP.[Transfer-from Code] IS NULL
)
```